# Find x intercept using linear interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am taking a course in numerical analysis at the moment and am quite new to matlab. This is a step in a larger assignment that I have been given.

I have a set of values, 69 values for x and y, for a curve where I want to solve the x-intercept. I don't have the corresponding value for x=0 though.

My idea was to interpolate linearly between the points closest to 0 to get the coefficients for a straight line and then solve for x=0, but I can't really figure out how to do it.

I have found the closest values to x=0 and stored them in vectors:

```
x = [0.251287 0.2555517];
y = [0.014228 -0.003326];
```

So I already know that the x-intercept is around 0.25.

My approach was to use interp1:

```
pp = interp1(x,y,'linear','pp');
```

And then use the coefficients I get from pp to solve it. The coefficients are -4.11677 and 0.014228. If I use these values for x=0 however I get an answer that is very far off, 0.003456.

I get a feeling that something in my approach is all wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interp1` is meant to interpolate values in between the two points. So the 2nd coefficient you get is simply the y value of your 1st pair of points. If you want to use `interp1`, you need to extrapolate to outside of the domain between your two x-values, but it would be a very clunky way of doing a linear regression.

Instead, you should use `polyfit` to fit your data to a polynomial of the order of your choice. You can do it on the whole data set, or on the 2 pairs of values that you have identified. Since in the second case, you are already using a linear regression (polynomial of order 1), you would do:

```
p = polyfit(x,y,1)
```

and `p(2)` will be your y-intercept. The x-intercept would be:

```
x-intercept = -p(2)/p(1)
```

See the Matlab info on `polyfit` [HERE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).

Comment: If I use polyfit on my 2 pairs of values, p stores two values: -4.11677 and 1.04872. The first value is the same as the one I got from interp1 but the second is different. 


If I use the coeffiecients from the polyfit as k and m in the linear equation y=kx+m and solve for y=0 I find x to 0.25474. This seems to be the correct answer.



Why then are the answers from polyfit different from those in interp1. It seems to me like they should be the same.

Comment: If you want the intercept, you should be looking for x = 0, not y = 0.

Comment: I want the x intercept, so when the curve crosses the x-axis. You are referring to the y intercept. But I got a good answer using polyfit nevertheless, so that was very helpful. Do you have any idea why the results from interp1 and polyfit are so different?

Comment: @Victoria: `interp1` is meant to interpolate values in between the two points. So the 2nd coefficient you get is simply the y value of your 1st pair of points. If you want to use `interp1`, you need to `extrapolate` to outside of the domain between your two `x-values`, but it would be a very clunky way of doing a linear regression.

Comment: If `polyfit` did help, please give an upvote and mark it as correct answer! Thanks!